# vim-powerline status line looks wierd

Tags: vim-powerline

I installed powerline plugin, downloaded a patched font and did a `fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts`. I then cleared the `PowerlineClearCache` and restarted vim. My status line looks like this. What am I missing?

NORMAL ⮀ Scripts/os_walk.py ⮀                                              ⮂ unix ⮃ utf-8 ⮃ python ⮂   8% ⮂ ⭡   2:1

I have this line in my .vimrc
`let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'`

Comment: I dont understand why I got down voted for this query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying this on mac OSX (Leopard) and apparently many mac users have this problem. Then I downloaded iterm2 and tried the steps suggested by this fantastic post and now it works as expected![image]
http://alexyoung.org/2012/01/13/using-powerline-with-mac-os/